# Docker containers as Linux services?

Tags: linux, service, docker, daemon, docker-registry

I just created a secure [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) and ran it on a remote VM (using `docker run ...`). I then ran `docker ps` and saw that it is in fact running. I exited the machine and then SSHed back in. Again, I ran `docker ps` and verified it "survived" me exiting the SSH session.

This has me wondering: **do Docker containers actually run as Linux services?** If not, is there any way of getting them to run as traditional (`upstart`- or `systemd`-based) services? Is there even any reason/merit to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker engine runs as a daemon.
That is mentioned in "[Host integration](https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/)":

> As of Docker 1.2, [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) are the built-in Docker mechanism for restarting containers when they exit. If set, restart policies will be used when the Docker daemon starts up, as typically happens after a system boot. Restart policies will ensure that linked containers are started in the correct order.
>
> If restart policies don’t suit your needs (i.e., you have non-Docker processes that depend on Docker containers), you can use a process manager like **[`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)**, [`systemd`](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or **[`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/)** instead.

---

That involves (when a container runs with some options) some security fraught, by the way: see [issue 14767](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14767) and [issue 6401](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6401#issuecomment-46361431):

> The container (with `--net host` option) is the host when it comes to the network stack so any services running on the host are accessible to the container. It just so happens that you communicate to upstart ( and others ) this way.
>
> This feature is a runtime only option, just like the `--privileged` flag, therefore an image cannot request this, it must be explicitly set at runtime.